# Creating Fields in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am using this code for adding a custom field (column) in a sharepoint list

```
   executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(shptService.appWebUrl);
                var data = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' }, 'Title': 'Col', 'FieldTypeKind': 3 }";
                executor.executeAsync({
                    url: shptService.appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/getbytitle(\'mylist\')/fields?@target='" + shptService.appWebUrl + "'",
                    method: "POST",
                    body: data,
                    headers: {
                        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                    }, success: function (data) { console.log('Success creating custom Field'); },
                    error: function (err) { conosole.log('Failed for creating custom Field !' + err); }

                });
```

it's working though, i want to create two or more fields at the same time.. is it possible in REST ??

Comment: hosted app or provider hosted app?

Comment: sharepoint hosted application sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch requests were not supported in SharePoint REST until recently. However, SharePoint Online has now got support for batch requests. You can find more details about it in the following links.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-1-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-understanding-batching-requests

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-2-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-exploring-batch-requests-responses-and-changesets